# Trying To Get More MH/s Litecoin Mining

Tags: litecoin, cgminer, gpu

I am relatively new to this but do have technical abilities like overclocking, etc. Here's what I'm working with:

> AMD A6 3620 APU w/Rade
>   Radeon HD 6530D
>   Driver: AMD Catalyst 15.7.1
>   Win 7 64 bit Home Premium

Also installed the recommended SDK for the AMD.

Tried both the cgminer from Kalrof and the version included in the GUIMiner -script download, and the best is around 42-43 KH/s. Tried the full GUIMiner and it was too unstable to connect on my system...it seems.

Been looking around and finding people with (what seems to be) lesser graphics getting above 100, and some in the area of 200 KH/s. If I can get into the 80-100 MH/s I would be happy. So I have tried all their settings, and keep getting lower numbers than I had to start with, or the driver crashes...which brings me to the second issue.

If I set the intensity above 16 the driver will crash. It reloads, but CGMiner stops working and has to be reloaded, too. This also happens when using xintensity above 225...and at 225 cgminer crashed after three days.

I've played with everything I can think of, in the .conf file and through flags. Any help would be sincerely appreciated! I want to do this, but if it's gonna take 3 months to get a single litecoin then I may as well go back to writing... tongue.gif

Also: Would it be possible to use both the GPU and the APU simultaneously? I haven't found much on this subject anywhere...

Here's a link to the complete specs on the Radeon: http://www.pc-specs....on_HD_6530D/489

Here's a look at my .bat, file:

```
setx GPU_MAX_ALLOC_PERCENT 100
setx GPU_USE_SYNC_OBJECTS 1
cgminer.exe --scrypt -o stratum+tcp://global.wemineltc.com:3333 -u user.worker -p pwd
```

AND the CONF:

```
{
"pools" : [
{
"url" : "stratum+tcp://global.wemineltc.com:3333",
"user" : "user/worker",
"pass" : "pwd"
},
{
"url" : "stratum+tcp://global.wemineltc.com:3333",
"user" : "user/worker",
"pass" : "pwd"
}
], 
"xintensity" : "330", (had to change this to 225 due to crashes after about 30 mins.)
"vectors" : "1",
"worksize" : "256",
"lookup-gap" : "0",
"gpu-threads" : "1",
"thread-concurrency" : "0",
"gpu-engine" : "0-0",
"gpu-fan" : "0-85",
"gpu-memclock" : "0",
"gpu-memdiff" : "0",
"gpu-powertune" : "0",
"gpu-vddc" : "0.000",
"temp-cutoff" : "95",
"temp-overheat" : "85",
"temp-target" : "75",
"api-mcast-port" : "4028",
"api-port" : "4028",
"expiry" : "120",
"failover-switch-delay" : "60",
"gpu-dyninterval" : "10",
"gpu-platform" : "0",
"log" : "5",
"log-dateformat" : "0",
"no-pool-disable" : true,
"no-client-reconnect" : true,
"queue" : "1",
"scan-time" : "30",
"scrypt" : true,
"temp-hysteresis" : "3",
"shares" : "0",
"kernel-path" : "/usr/local/bin"
}
```

Again, THANKS for any help you can provide!

Comment: Please fix the [formatting](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/editing-help): E.g. four spaces will give you "preformatted text", allowing you to present your config in a readable fashion. However, today, using a GPU instead of an ASIC for mining, is like using a spoon to compete with a dredger.

Comment: "Been looking around and finding people with (what seems to be) lesser graphics getting above 100, and some in the area of 200 KH/s. If I can get into the 80-100 MH/s I would be happy."
I think you are comparing speeds of mining SHA-256 with your mining Scrypt. Mining SHA-256 will have vastly higher hashrates. However, afaik even Litecoin has surpassed its GPU mining phase.

Answer (score 1):

[Mining hardware comparision on Litecoin.info](https://litecoin.info/Mining_hardware_comparison) lists an "AMD 6530D" with a hashrate of `47 kH/s`. This is in the same range as what you achieve. The higher numbers you found were probably associated with a different mining algorithm instead of `Scrypt` which you are performing when mining Litecoin.

However, the age for GPU mining is over for Scrypt mining just as it is with Bitcoin mining. Although, I was talking about Bitcoin, this longer explanation applies to Litecoin just as well: 
[In the ASIC-age, is it worth starting mining Bitcoin at home?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/41276/5406)